# Python Storing Generated Classe Objects into an Array

Tags: python, arrays, class, object

I'm currently working on a way of generating a bunch of class objects and storing them within the array and executing a class function without having to go through each one. The context that I have put the problem in isn't the exact same way as what I'm doing but its too complex to explain for just the question

Let's say I have information stored in an array like this:

```
x = [['dog', 1], ['cat',2]]
```

The class will appear like this:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, position):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position

    def display(self):
        print(self.name, self.position)
```

So my objective is to take the information from the array and store them as objects into an empty array. The reason for this is to be able to call a function from all objects without having to repeat it for every object without iteration.

My issue below is that I'm appending them into the list but the object doesn't have a variable name attached to it. Is there a way to make the variable name `value[0]` which would be the name contained in `x`.

```
empty = []

for value in x:
    empty.append(Animal(value[0], value[1]))
```

Then once that has stored properly to execute them would this following code work?

```
for item in empty:
item.display()
```

I understand you shouldn't use this to print just the values, but I put it into this scenario to keep it simple in what to do with the class.

Comment: Did you try this? It works fine.

Comment: _"I'm appending them into the list but the object doesn't have a variable name attached to it."_ ... Yes, that is how lists work. Elements in a list don't have variable names. Why would you need one? You can just index the list to get what you want.

Comment: @Kevin So the created class object can be stored directly without being first assigned a variable name?

Comment: Yes. That's not unique to user-defined classes, either. You can store built-in type instances without first assigning them a variable name; ex. `my_list.append(23)` instead of having to do `thing = 23; my_list.append(thing)`

Comment: @Vexoids It's the other way around, the variable name is assigned to the instance. It's like a label hanging on a bottle. You can have as many labels as you like on a bottle. You can take a label and hang it on another bottle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will work (given appropriate indentation).

Btw. the easiest way to get an answer is just run the code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, but maybe you looking for [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

File observer.py

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, position):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
    def update(self, message):
        print('{} at {} got message "{}"'.format(self.name, self.position, message))

class Publisher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subscribers = set()
    def register(self, who):
        self.subscribers.add(who)
    def unregister(self, who):
        self.subscribers.discard(who)
    def dispatch(self, message):
        for subscriber in self.subscribers:
            subscriber.update(message)
```

File driver_observer.py

```
from observer import Publisher, Animal

pub = Publisher()

dog = Animal('dog', 1)
cat = Animal('cat', 2)

pub.register(dog)
pub.register(cat)

pub.dispatch("something")

pub.unregister(dog)

pub.dispatch("another thing")
```

When execute driver_observer.py:

```
dog at 1 got message "something"
cat at 2 got message "something"
cat at 2 got message "another thing"
```

[link](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1743/2015/06/17/tutorial-the-observer-pattern-in-python)

Answer (score -2):

Use a __dict__ to get fields and values

```
dog = Animal('dog', 1)
dict_to_store = dog.__dict__
```

On your object get a dict of yours fields and values

```
animal = Animal()
animal.__dict_.update(dict_to_store)
```